# Use array field in $cond

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to set a value in my aggregation pipeline based on if any object in an array has a specific value set to true.

```
            {
                $set: {
                    "read": {$cond: {if: {"permissions.publicRead": true}, then: true, else: false}},
                    "write": false,
                    "owner": false
                }
            }
```

But its complaining about not allowing a "." in the field name. The data looks something like this:

```
{
    "permissions": [
        {"publicRead": true},
        {"publicRead": false}
    ]
}
```

Edit:
I also tried using `$permissions.publicRead` and `{if: "permissions.publicRead", then: true, else: false}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reason of error:**
`$cond` requires to check condition in `$eq` operator and need to pass `$` before `$permissions.publicRead` in condition,

> ```
> $cond: { 
>   if: { $eq: ["$permissions.publicRead", true] }, then: true, else: false 
> }
> ```

After resolving above problem the query will work without error but it will not return right result because,
the `permissions.publicRead` will always return array of boolean values,

> `$eq: ["$permissions.publicRead", true]`
>
> is equal to
>
> `$eq: [[true, false], true]` or `$eq: [[false, true], true]`
>
> so
>
> `[true, false]` or `[false, true]` is not equal to `true`

---

Try [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) operator to check is array have any true value or not,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "read": {
        $anyElementTrue: "$permissions.publicRead"
      },
      "write": false,
      "owner": false
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6dyZAPwS9Wq)

Comment: Ill test that out. Mind giving me a hint how I could make this work for non boolean objects as well? Like when checking if a string has a value instead of a bool being true

Comment: well check the provided link in answer, there is a statement might help you *the false boolean value, $anyElementTrue evaluates as false the following: null, 0, and undefined values. The $anyElementTrue evaluates all other values as true, including non-zero numeric values and arrays.* string can't work.